# Inheriting code for ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using ASP.NET web forms in Visual Studio 2010. How can I create UI controls and such programmatically? For example, I want to define in separate form files to have a side-bar menu and such, and then the resulting pages will inherit that functionality. In my base class, I added a new control to `this.Controls`, but generating the page throws an exception, saying that the control must be placed inside a tag with `runat="server"`. If I want to generate these controls programmatically, how do I place them inside such a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> *and then the resulting pages will inherit that functionality*

which makes me believe you are better off using Master Pages, here's [a tutorial on ASP.NET master pages](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials) (use Google to find more). However, inheritance itself can also easily be achieved by taking any existing control and extending it:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    // your extensions and overrides
}
```

---

Later you write:

> *I added a new control to this.Controls, but generating the page throws an exception, saying that the control must be placed inside a tag with runat="server".*

which is not entirely related. This is simply true: every server control must have a `runat="server"`_ or it won't be recognized by the ASP.NET parser. I.e., like this:

```
<!-- existing server control, placed on a page -->
<asp:Label runat="server" Id="MyOwnLabel" />
<!-- your own server control, placed on a page -->
<my:MyTextBox runat="server" ID="ReallyMyTextBox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a tad bit confused. It sounds like you're trying to add elements across various pages programmatically. In ASP.NET this isn't required.

I believe what you are looking for (and what would be the right tool for the job) would be [ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).

Master Pages will allow you to define a kind of template for your pages with common content (like navigation, ad bars, etc.).